# How to store business hours in mongodb with the possibility of lunch time?

Tags: mongodb

I have searched for similar questions but none of them was able to solve my doubt.
My current idea is to have a hash with the day names as keys, and an 
array of hashes for the opening hours:

```
{ 
  mon : [ { start : 7.5, end : 18 } ] , 
  tue : [ {start : 7.5, end : 12 }, {start : 16, end : 20}] 
... 
}
```

but I'm not sure if and how I can index this representation for 
queries such as "who's open now?" to run quickly enough. 
Does anyone knows what are the best practices for this case? 
The lunch time is really a pain, but I need be able to handle this type of case correctly. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the lunch time is a fixed slot or it can vary?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understant what you meant with fixed slot.

Comment: ex. Lunch hour is fixed such as 12.00 - 13.00, 13.00 to 14.00 or it can vary